# when I want to write npm intall and npm run serve in Terminal in vs code then I get some errors in nmp install and serve. what can I do?

Tags: vue.js

I have some errors in npm i:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)    
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\all web design\\all\\Web class\\Vue Js\\free template\\good template\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

when I want to write npm intall and npm run serve in Terminal in vs code then I get some errors in nmp install and serve. what can I do?

and one error in npm run serve:

```
Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                   10:55:49 AM
 error  in ./src/assets/sass/black-dashboard.scss

Syntax Error: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
Require stack:
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getDefaultSassImplementation.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getSassImplementation.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\cjs.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\vue.config.js
- D:\all web design\all\Web class\Vue Js\free template\good template\package.json


 @ ./src/assets/sass/black-dashboard.scss 4:14-244 15:3-20:5 16:22-252
 @ ./src/plugins/blackDashboard.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.102:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Comment: May be `npm install node-sass` can help you?

Comment: that's the crucial part in your error messages: `Can't find Python executable "python"`

Comment: @7-zete-7
no, I do npm install node-sass again I get these errors.

Comment: Looks like the package you want to install needs python. So you need to install python first.